# How can I find the time I fast booted my windows 8 computer this morning?

Tags: windows-8, boot

I have a Windows 8.1 laptop at work which I turn off every evening and turn on every morning. I want to know at what time I started my computer this morning. However, I use the fast boot option. This means that all the options I could find for Windows 7 (eventlog warning 100, `wmic os get lastbootuptime`, `systeminfo | find /i "Boot Time"`, Task manager performance tab) don't apply, because they all find my reboot for Windows Update yesterday, not my fast boot from this morning. I also surprisingly cannot find anything on Google, with all options talking about how to enable (or sometimes disable) the Fast boot on Windows 8.1.

What fast boot compatible options are there to figure out at what time I booted my laptop this morning (or a past morning)?

Comment: Does the Event Viewer show anything as to when the computer woke up? If you look through the viewer you may see some regular entries at the times it wakes up? Because Windows 8 uses a hybrid hibernate/shutdown then, as experienced, you're not getting the full shutdown/startup events. A reboot does cause this for precisely things like updates.

Comment: @BigChris The problem is that I have absolutely no idea what to look for in the event viewer. There are so many different logbooks, and when checking the logbook where you check for warning 100, I get only 2 warnings in the possible timeframe (8-8:30 AM), but those also appear an hour later as well.

Comment: I've checked eventviewer some more. I found an option. I'll add it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more browsing of the event logs and found a solution.

Open the System logbook in the Windows Logbooks root folder. then filter for events of level information with event ID 1. this will show 2 different events: one from the Kernel-General, one from the Power-Troubleshooter. The Kernel-General event is a notification that the system time has changed. the Power-troubleshooter event is what you need: "The system has exited a state of low energy use". It even says when this energy use started and when it ended.